# How to use different scaling approaches in weka

Tags: java, machine-learning, statistics, weka, logistic-regression

I am using `logistic regression` with my data in weka. Now I want to try different scaling approaches to improve my results, such as min/max, zero mean/unit, variance, length etc.

Is there any option in weka for using scaling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weka includes methods for data preprocessing:

```
weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Normalize
weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Standardize
```

In Java:

```
Instances train_data = ...   
Instances test_data = ...    
Standardize filter = new Standardize();
filter.setInputFormat(train_data);  
Instances normalizedTrain_data = Filter.useFilter(train_data, filter);  
Instances normalizedTest_data = Filter.useFilter(test_data, filter);
```

In Weka Explorer, under "Filter" choose the "Standardize" filter and apply it to all attributes. Check this [tutorial](http://uic.edu.hk/~wfsu/courses/2009-2010/comp4090/tutorials/comp_4090_t2.htm) for more details.

Comment: Btw one final question, what does the standardize filter do in weka. Is there also a min/max filter?

Comment: @user2051347 I think Normliaze filter is a min/max one, while standardize is to eliminate the mean value then divides std.Thanks